# Latest Chrome: float inside of -webkit-column broken

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-float, multiple-columns

Intended form layout using columns:

> key: <kbd>value</kbd>     **|**     key: <kbd>value</kbd>     **|**     key: <kbd>value</kbd>
>
> key: <kbd>value</kbd>     **|**     key: <kbd>value</kbd>     **|**     key: <kbd>value</kbd>
>
> key: <kbd>value</kbd>     **|**     key: <kbd>value</kbd>     **|**

`key` being fixed-width `float: left` inside of a multi-column layout.

```html
<form>
    <label>
        <span>key:</span>
        <span><input value="value"/></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>key:</span>
        <span><input value="value"/></span>
    </label>
    ...
</form>
```

As soon as setting `-webkit-column-count` on the `<form>`, the latest Chrome renders 'key' and <kbd>value</kbd> on top of each other.

Idea behind the floats is to allow the <kbd>value</kbd> input fields to take up the rest of the available space.

see http://jsfiddle.net/99ckf72q/, working as intended in Firefox.

Bug in WebKit?

Comment: It’s only broken in the latest versions of webkit browsers which supports my idea of being a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be fixed in Chrome `45.0.2454.9` / WebKit build `537.36`

Comment: Bug still present in current Opera (user agent string `Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36 OPR/32.0.1948.25`).

Answer (score -1):

its not a webkit bug. you are not using the column count properly correctly. when you use column count its better to avoid float and display block.
Try with the below CSS.

```
form  {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
form label {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
label {
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: This renders key and value evenly distributed which was not intended: Label need to have a fixed width of 100px, value to take up the rest. Also, how is your solution of nested columns more 'correct' than using floats?

Comment: if you wanted a fixed with you can use float/width. and your issue is key and values are on top of each other, for that I provided the solution and you applied the same on jsfiddle :). instud of giving a width and float, I slept the label into two column.

Comment: The idea was to combine fixed-width floats for the keys (in order to allow the value input fields to take up the rest of the available space) and multiple columns for a flexible horizontal layout using more columns for wider screens. Your answer only addresses the overlapping while dismissing these details of the intended result. I updated the question accordingly, to reflect the problem more illustrative.